# Ubuntu 20.04 does not recognize my WiFi card

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04

This morning I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04. The network card seems completely unavailable. It is old, since it was supported with 14.04, 16.04, and 18.04.

The WiFi Setting shows blank - no Visible Networks.

The following is copied by hand, since I have no network to copy it to this machine!

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep Network
02:00:00 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
```

```
$ lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network | grep Kernel
   Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
```

```
$ iwconfig
[...]
 wlan0 IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any
       Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated  Tx-Power=20 dBm
       Retry short limit:7  RTS thr=2347 B  Fragment thr:off
       Power Management:off
[...]
```

`sudo ifconfig wlan0 down` and then `sudo ifconfig wlan0 up` had no effect.

What do I try next?

Comment: Look at, but don't post `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`.

Answer (score 0):

This is now resolved.  Following the successful upgrade to 20.04, in my frustration with the lack of network, I re-booted into 20.04.  No joy.  Rebooted again into 20.04.  No joy.  Re-booted into 18.04.  No joy.  Rebooted into 20.04.  Bingo!  Since then, after three successful daily re-boots, I have had no further problem.